# What's the complexity of Spearman's rank correlation coefficient computation?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, counting-complexity, time-complexity

I've been studyin' the [Spearman's rank correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient).
If computed for two list that have both size $N$, what's the complexity of the algorithm?

$O(N)$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Technically you need to sort it first. Btw this question might be better off at cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question was [cross-posed to CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2604/55) where it was answered. Next time please ask the moderators to migrate your question instead of multiple posts that splinter conversation.